# C++ No-repeat random number generator

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, random, permutation

I need to create algorithm implementation in C++ to generate random numbers to f.e table without repeat and list.

I created something code like that but it's stop working when I put n=32769 in console program stop working. When i put number in range 0-32768 it's works. Any idea what is wrong in this code? 
While compilation i had no errors/warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    int n;
    std::cout << "n:";
    std::cin >> n;
    bool *used_numbers = new bool[n];
    memset(used_numbers, false, sizeof(used_numbers[0]) * n);
    int *permutation = new int[n];
    srand(unsigned(std::time(NULL)));
     int rnd_number;



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        rnd_number = rand() % n;
        if (!used_numbers[rnd_number])
        {
            permutation[i] = rnd_number;
            used_numbers[rnd_number] = true;
        }
        else
            i--;
    }
    std::cout << "Permutation: \n ";
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        std::cout << permutation[k] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    printf("[Debug]: %lu ms\n", clock() - start);




    getchar();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it stopped working? Does it crash? Does it output the wrong thing? Does it infinite loop?

Comment: "_While compilation i had no errors/warnings._" If the program compiles, it doesn't mean that it works correctly.

Comment: What is the value of `RAND_MAX` on your machine when you print it?

Comment: I'm guessing that the implementation of `rand()` that you're using generates values in the range [0 .. 32767], which is not at all uncommon. Generating 32768 values will inevitably create at least one duplicate. Check the value of `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: This is likely to do with the range of an signed integer.  An unsigned int will likely give you a range of 0 to 65,535.

Comment: @pcgben Not necessarily. An int is defined to be anything between 16 and 32 bits, and on most modern systems, it's going to be 32 bits.

Comment: @Aderis -- an `int` is required to be **at least** 16 bits wide. There is no maximum size. Its actual definition is determined by the compiler.

Comment: This isn't the immediate problem, but this algorithm leaves a great deal to be desired. Use `std::shuffle`. Or, if you want the theory, read about the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rand() % n
```

will never give you a number larger than RAND_MAX. RAND_MAX is the range of the numbers generated by rand().

If you use a value of n larger than RAND_MAX, you will loop forever after you draw the first RAND_MAX numbers. Simply, there's no numbers left to draw.

You need to improve your solution to be able to generate larger numbers, or use something better like shuffling a larger list of numbers.

Your algorithm has many issues, but an immediate simple fix would be:

```
rnd_number = (rand() * (RAND_MAX + 1) + rand()) % n;
```

Comment: This replacement creates a slightly skewed generator. For example, if the leftmost call to rand() returns 0 and the rightmost call returns RAND_MAX you get the value RAND_MAX. But if the leftmost one returns 1 and the rightmost one returns 0 you also get RAND_MAX. The multiplier on the left should be `(RAND_MAX + 1)`. Upvoted, however, as it's a valid answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are right. But as far as skewness goes for diy-random-schemes, it was way milder than stuff I've seen. Like rand()*rand(). :-). Still, fixed, thanks.

Comment: `rand()*rand()`? Wow.

Comment: This is not a valid answer because algorithm of `rand` is unspecified so it may produce repetitive results and so on.

Comment: @VTT we're not talking about crypto security here. The OP wrote an algorithm and runs into an issue with it. What the OP most likely needs is to understand where it goes amiss. This answer points out where the problem is and a minimal fix. The answer might not be perfect, but 'not valid' is pushing it. Your LFSR is interesting, but clearly above the level where it has value for the OP

Answer (score 0):

I just want to state some other solutions to the following problems, which may work faster (or with some shorter code) (in some cases).

Imagine the case where you need all the elements of the set {0, 1, .., n - 1}, probability of choosing the last non-chosen element(in last iteration) is equal to 1/n, expected value is then n iterations for picking only one element.

1. ```
   vector<int> p;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) p.push_back(i);
   random_shuffle(p.begin(), p.end();
   ```

and then you can take first K elements of vector p (or whole vector, if you need the whole permutation).

2. In every iteration, you can pick a random number i between 1 and numbers_left (N - numbers_already_chosen), and then take i-th number that hasn't been already picked. It may also be inefficient, but using some binary search + binary indexed tree, you could get to O(Nlog^2N), maybe even better.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to generate a sequence of non-crypto-safe numbers without a repeat then you can utilize [Linear-feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). Example generation 65535 items (adopted from Wiki):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

int main(void)
{
    // Any nonzero start state will work.
    const ::std::uint16_t start_state{0xACE1u};
    ::std::uint16_t lfsr{start_state};
    ::std::uint64_t period{0};
#ifndef NDEBUG
    ::std::set<::std::uint16_t> used_items{};
#endif // #ifndef NDEBUG
    do
    {
        // Get LSB (i.e., the output bit).
        bool lsb{0 != (lfsr & 1)};
        // Shift register
        lfsr >>= 1;
        // If the output bit is 1, apply toggle mask.
        if(lsb)
        {
            lfsr ^= 0xB400u;
        }
        // verify that current value has never appeared before
        assert(used_items.emplace(lfsr).second);
        std::cout << lfsr << "\n";
        ++period;
    }
    while(lfsr != start_state);
    ::std::cout << "period " << period << "\n";
    ::std::cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```